# Getting closest observations using Euclidean distance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
ID PC1   PC2
12 0.355 0.362
24 0.577 0.425
15 0.257 0.486
06 0.585 0.254
34 0.367 0.533
```

I want to use Euclidean distance on PC1 and PC2 to get the closest data points.

So my desired out is that when I put in `ID = 15` in python, I want it to give me a list of 3 data points that are the closest. Desired output would look like this.

```
ID PC1   PC2   Distance
34 0.367 0.533 ###
06 0.585 0.254 ###
12 0.355 0.462 ###
```

The numbers above are made up, but that’s what I want my output to look like. ‘Distance’ is the distance from the input data point (ID=15) to each respective data point in the output.

I know this is fairly simple, but I am a beginner python learner. I am a little unsure of how to approach this so can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure for your output? I found (34, 12, 24).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to to query many points, you may want to construct a `KDTree` first. Here is an example using `scipy`:

```
from scipy import spatial

# WARNING: This assumes that all points in the DataFrame are distinct.

# construct a KDTree given a set of points
tree = spatial.cKDTree(df[["PC1", "PC2"]])
# get four = three + one points closest to a given point (index 15 in this case)
# the query point itself will be part of the output
distances, indices = tree.query(df.loc[15].values, k=3+1)
# get the df of near points
df_near = df.iloc[indices[1:]].assign(Distance=distances[1:])

print(df_near)
#       PC1    PC2  Distance
# ID                        
# 34  0.367  0.533  0.119620
# 12  0.355  0.362  0.158051
# 24  0.577  0.425  0.325762
```

Comment: Great, we have the same output :)

Comment: You suppose the 'ID' column is the index of the dataframe (`df.loc[15]`). I don't think so, maybe, you have to `set_index`. Next, check the 4th ID -> '06' and not 6, so the dtype of column ID is probably `str` and not `int`.

Comment: You are probably right about input format. I used `StringIO` + `pd.read_csv` to parse the table, which presumably converted "ID" column to integers.

Comment: And the last point (I had the same problem...). Add a row at the beginning of your dataframe like `03  0.257  0.486`. You will filtered out '03' and keep '15'.

Comment: Argh, I assumed unique points but fair enough. I think I will rather add a disclaimer and leave this issue to someone more motivated.

Comment: Try: `tree = spatial.cKDTree(df.loc[df.index != 15, ['PC1', 'PC2']]);
distances, indices = tree.query(df.loc[15].values, k=3);
df_near = df.iloc[indices].assign(Distance=distances)`

Comment: I appreciate how this fixes this particular example; however, this approach will require knowing _the_ query index before constructing the KDTree, which sort of defeats the purpose. If only one point needs to be queried, there is no need to construct the KDTree.

Comment: You are totally right. I'm agree with that.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ID = '15'

# Extract PC1, PC2 from current point (ID='15')
point = df.loc[df['ID'] == ID, ['PC1', 'PC2']].squeeze()

# Keep all other points
others = df.loc[df['ID'] != ID, ['PC1', 'PC2']]

# Compute the distance between the point and the other points
# and keep the 3 points with the smallest distance
dist = (others - point).pow(2).sum(1).pow(0.5).nsmallest(3)
out = df.loc[dist.index].assign(Distance=dist)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   ID    PC1    PC2  Distance
4  34  0.367  0.533  0.119620
0  12  0.355  0.362  0.158051
1  24  0.577  0.425  0.325762
```